# Find all values of $a$ for which there are two real solutions of $x^3-2ax^2+a^2x-3=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, parametric, cubics

Find all values of $a$ for which there are two real solutions of the equation.

$$x^3-2ax^2+a^2x-3=0$$

Ans = $1.5\sqrt[3]{6}$

I tried to research the function by dint of derivative, but it didn't give me anything.

Comment: Hint: think of the cubic graph. For two real solutions, we need two stationary points for the graph. Moreover, the $y$-value for the minimum point should be negative and the $y$-value for the maximum point should be positive.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_polynomial#The_nature_of_the_roots

Comment: My opinion is that for the value $a=1.5\sqrt[3]{6}$ the equation has double real root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to plot a graph of a cubic function. In your case it's $-\infty$ on the left, going concave, then going convex and then increasing to $+\infty$.

A cubic function has three (with multiplicity) roots. If two are real, then the third is real, too (hint: coefficient at $x^0$), therefore, two roots must coincide, but not all three.

Hence, our function must have the form $(x-b)(x-c)^2$, $b\ne c$. By looking at the derivatives of zeroth, first, and second order, you can build a system of equations on $a$, $b$, $c$ and obtain the expression for $a$.

Another approach, as suggested by @gnasher729, is to simply open the parantheses and match coefficients at different powers of $x$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you explain for what I must find the derivatives of zeroth, first.. order?

Comment: You can just multiply (x-b)(x-c)^2 = x^3 - (2c+b)x^2 + (c^2 + 2bc)x - bc^2, which must match x^3 - 2ax^2 + a^2x - 3, and then you get three equations because the coefficients for x^2, x, and the constant term must be the same. Better check this for errors first :-)

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is to consider the equation as an equation for $a$ first. In this way you will get
$$xa^2-2x^2a+x^3-3=0$$

Then $D = x^4-x(x^3-3)=3x$ and $a_1=\frac{x-\sqrt{3x}}{x}$ and  $a_1=\frac{x+\sqrt{3x}}{x}$
then you can factor the equation as follows
$x(a-\frac{x-\sqrt{3x}}{x})(a-\frac{x+\sqrt{3x}}{x})=0$. Now you have two  equations

$xa-x+\sqrt{3x}=0$

$xa-x-\sqrt{3x}=0$

Comment: Could you elaborate your solution? It's far from evident how you can obtain the final result using this reasoning; in particular, you obtained a root $x=0$, which is obviously false.

Comment: You are right. I corrected the calculations

Answer (score 2):

As complex roots come in conjugates, there is a repeated root. This means there exists a $x_0$ where $f(x_0)=f'(x_0)=0$

Solving $f'(x_0)=0$ gives a quadratic with roots $a,a/3$

As function is non zero at $a$, this implies $f(a/3)=0\implies a^3(1/27-2/9+1/3)-3=0$

This gives you the desired result.